# Своя стилизация Csort в yii

Tags: php, html, yii

Доброго времени суток!

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, каким образом можно изменить html представление сортировки? Сортировку создаю с помощью класса `CSort`, далее передаю в `DataProvider` и вывожу элементы с помощью `CListView`.

Имеется в виду, можно ли сменить расположение сортировки стандартными методами yii, а не через css и js/jq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить можно. Покопайся в `СListView`. Там есть свойство `'template'=>"{sorter}{pager}\n{items}"` можно ним поиграться + метод `renderSorter()`. Копай в эту сторону.

[Документация по `СListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView).